# TKinter call one class from other class using TOPLEVEL modal dialogue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have two python files named as .Both files are placed [com ] package
scr1.py
scr2.py
When I click "next" button in scr1 ,I need to call other class src2 using toplevel_dialog
But I'm unable to call the other class [scr2.py ].Please suggest me what I need to modify

scr1.py

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk 
import tkinter as tk 
import com.scr2
root = Tk()   
def Create_Toplevel():
        print("inside Create_Toplevel method") 
        top = Toplevel( com.scr2)  
        top.mainloop() 

class scr1():
    root.title("Employee Details")
    root.geometry("350x270") 
    T = Text(root, height = 5, width = 15) 
    
    l = Label(root, text = "Employee Id") 
    l.config(font =("Courier", 10)) 
    EmployeeId = "500" 
    b1 = Button(root, text = "Next", command= Create_Toplevel() ) 
    T.insert(tk.END, EmployeeId)   
    l.pack() 
    T.pack() 
    b1.pack() 
        
def Close_Toplevel():
           print("inside Close_Toplevel method") 

   
def main():     
    scr1obj = scr1()   
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

src2.py

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk 
import tkinter as tk 
root = Tk()  
class scr2(): 
    root.title("Employee Details")
    root.geometry("350x270") 
    T = Text(root, height = 5, width = 10)     
    Label1= Label(root, text = "Employee Address") .place(x=30,y=30)
    T1= Text(root, height = 2, width = 20) .place(x=140,y=30)    
    Label2= Label(root, text = "MailId") .place(x=30,y=100)
    T2= Text(root, height = 2, width = 20) .place(x=140,y=80)
    b1 = Button(root, text = "confirm Details") .place(x=190,y=150)     

def main():     
    scr2obj = scr2()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: _"But I'm unable to call the other class"_ ? Why? Does it show any error? And  I dont think this is how you properly define a class, I would suggest to watch tutorials on OOP with tkinter. For the time being, try replacing `class sc2` with `def sc2()`.

Comment: @CoolCloud replacing class sc2 with def sc2() but it shows error like "AttributeError: module 'example.scr2' has no attribute '_last_child_ids' "  Application not running